# How to handle 403 error to calling SharePoint list from android?

Tags: java, android, sharepoint, android-volley, sharepoint-online

I want to call SharePoint rest API form android. for this, i'm using cookies to call rest API using web view,  but while calling am getting "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403".

if l call to SharePoint rest api using volley here what i tried up to.
update:i'm using this site for refrence [SharePoint rest api from android](https://asheshany.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/connecting-to-sharepoint-2013-online-365-apis-in-android/)
**Update:during research i found one example to connect with share point online using soap as well, any idea how to do that? **

```
private void sendAndRequestResponse() {
    //RequestQueue initialized
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting volley request to graph");

    /* Make sure we have a token to send to graph */

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();

    try {
        parameters.put("key", "value");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to put parameters: " + e.toString());
    }
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            parameters,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Cookie","rtFa=" + RTFA + "; FedAuth=" + FedAuth);
            headers.put("Accept","application/json;odata=verbose");
            headers.put("Content-type","application/json;odata=verbose");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    Log.d(TAG, "Adding HTTP GET to Queue, Request: " + request.toString());

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            3000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(request);
}
```

I used rtfa and fed cookies  to pass as header.

**Update**: i used share point login URL for  windows auth. for and after success i store rfta and fed auth. cookies to pass token as header but i'm getting same error.

Comment: hello all any suggestion

Comment: Sorry.  Don't have experience with this. How about posting on `MSAL` GitHub site? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues

Comment: @DeanB_Develop i want to call rest API using raft and fed auth. cookies but while calling its showing error, i have no clue how to do this.